# How to connect to Azure sql database with python SQL alchemy using Active directory integrated authentication

Tags: python, sql, azure, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL Database using SQL Alchemy in python. The database was recently moved to Azure from on-prem and as I understand that azure does not support Windows Auth.
I can connect to the DB from SSMS using Active Directory Integrated Auth.

When the Db was on prem i would use the following connection string and it worked:

```
"mssql+pyodbc://@*Server*/*DB*?driver=SQL Server"
```

I have tried a few other connection string and cannot get it to work.

```
"mssql+pyodbc://@*Server*/*DB*?driver=SQL Server?Integrated Security=true"
"mssql+pyodbc://@*Server*/*DB*?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=true"
```

i keep getting the following error, it seems like sql alchemy is trying to connect via windows auth by default is there anyway i can fix this ?

```
(pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server. (40607) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server. (40607)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I known, all of your need are in the offical document [`Using Azure Active Directory with the ODBC Driver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-2017).

First, only the odbc driver 17 version for MS SQL Server supports Active Directory Integrated Authentication if you want to connect to Azure SQL Database by `pyodbc`. So please make sure you have installed the lastest odbc driver for SQL Server, or you can download from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017.

Second, please follow the section [`UI Additions for Azure Active Directory (Windows driver only)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-2017#ui-additions-for-azure-active-directory-windows-driver-only) to configure the DSN for Azure Active Directory Integrated authentication to SQL Azure.

Then, you can follow the code below to connect to SQL Azure by `SQL Alchemy` with `pyodbc`.

```
from urllib import parse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connecting_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<your sql azure server name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<your database name>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'
params = parse.quote_plus(connecting_string)

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select 1+1 as res")
for row in result:
    print("res:", row['res'])
connection.close()
```

Note: The value of connection string above, you can copy it from the `` tab on Azure portal, but please notice to change the odbc driver version and remove the `UID` and `PWD` options.

[image]

> To connect using Windows Integrated or Active Directory Integrated
>   (Windows driver only) authentication, specify
>   ***Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated*** in the connection string. The
>   driver will choose the correct authentication mode automatically. ***UID***
>   and ***PWD*** must not be specified.

Or you can consider to use `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword` which be easier than `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` and the code as below.

```
from urllib import parse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

your_user_name = '<your AAD user or configured in SQL Azure Server as the figure below>'
your_password_here = '<your AAD account password>'
#connecting_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:sqlserverleon.database.windows.net,1433;Database=dbleon;Uid='+your_user_name+';Pwd='+your_password_here+';Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword'
connecting_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:sqlserverleon.database.windows.net,1433;Database=dbleon;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'
params = parse.quote_plus(connecting_string)

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select 1+1 as res")
for row in result:
    print("res:", row['res'])
connection.close()
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the well articulated answer. Simply switching to ODBC Driver 17 worked for me.
Here is the connection string that worked:
"mssql+pyodbc://@*Server*/*Database*?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no"
for some reason it did not work when adding Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated