# How to connect to the sql azure database with python SQL alchemy using active directory integrated authentication

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-active-directory, ssms

I am using the connection string as below

```
params=parse.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 For SQL server};Server=tcp:server name,1433;database=database name;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'
engine=sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql:///?odbc_connect=%s" %params)
```

using the above connection string it is giving me the error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server][SQL server]111214 an attempt to an attempt to complete the transaction has failed no corresponding transaction found
```

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for the answer but i done know the password for that server as when i login from the SSMS through active directory -Integrated authentication so could you please help me on that part why i am getting the error as no transaction found

Comment: Please try my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can add `connect_args`, then try.

*Please make sure you have same account login your windows pc and sql server.*

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params, echo=True, connect_args={'autocommit': True})
```

**PREVIOUS**

You can consider to use `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword` which be easier than `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated`, and the code as below which is works for me.

Thank for [Peter Pan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989676/peter-pan)'s answer, for more details, you can refer his description. His answer has detailed usage of `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` in his description, I prefer `Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword`, so I posted my answer, you can refer to it.

[How to connect to Azure sql database with python SQL alchemy using Active directory integrated authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901728/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database-with-python-sql-alchemy-using-active-direct)

[image]

```
from urllib import parse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

your_user_name = 'pa**i@**a.onmicrosoft.com'
your_password_here = 'J***20'
connecting_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:yoursqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=yoursqldb;Uid='+your_user_name+';Pwd='+your_password_here+';Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword'
params = parse.quote_plus(connecting_string)

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select 1+1 as res")
for row in result:
    print("res:", row['res'])
connection.close()
```